# Deal with large data set for image classification

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, large-data

I am using keras for my image classification , here is my code:

```
train_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
        train_data_dir,
        target_size=(img_width, img_height),
        batch_size=batch_size,
        class_mode="categorical")

validation_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
        validation_data_dir,
        target_size=(img_width, img_height),
        batch_size=batch_size,
        class_mode="categorical")

Found 70000 images belonging to 15 classes.
Found 6000 images belonging to 15 classes.
```

Then i am using this data to fit into my model here is my code:

```
model.fit_generator(
        train_generator,
        steps_per_epoch=train_samples // batch_size,
        epochs=epochs,
        validation_data=validation_generator,
        validation_steps=validation_samples// batch_size,)
```

I have used various batch size, but result are insufficient  , my model is too slow to train it takes hours to train and also it crashes sometime , can someone please help to train model when we have large data set , how to do that efficiently ?

Model Code:

```
# a simple stack of 3 convolution layers with a ReLU activation and followed by max-pooling layers.
model = Sequential()
model.add(Convolution2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=(img_width, img_height,3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Convolution2D(32, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Convolution2D(64, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(64))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(15))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
```

Comment: Can you also post your neural network code ?

Comment: @MihaiAlexandru-Ionut added , additionally i also tried using VGG16 using bottle neck

Answer (score 0):

Well, one solution to increase the performance is to use `GPU`.

If you are running on the `TensorFlow` backend, your code will automatically run on **GPU** if any available **GPU** is detected.

```
pip install tensorflow-gpu
```

Also, you can choose to have `data parallelism` using `multi_gpu_model` class.

```
from keras.utils import multi_gpu_model

# Replicates `model` on 8 GPUs.
# This assumes that your machine has 8 available GPUs.
parallel_model = multi_gpu_model(model, gpus=8)
parallel_model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                       optimizer='rmsprop')

# This `fit` call will be distributed on 8 GPUs.
# Since the batch size is 256, each GPU will process 32 samples.
parallel_model.fit(x, y, epochs=20, batch_size=256)
```

I see that your output layer uses `sigmoid` as activation function. That's wrong. You have to use `softmax` because `sigmoid` is for `binary` classification or `two-class` models.

`Softmax` function calculates the probabilities distribution of the event over `n` different class.(15 in your case).

In general way of saying, this function will calculate the probabilities of each target class over all possible target classes. Later the calculated probabilities will be helpful for determining the target class for the given inputs.

The main advantage of using `Softmax` is the output probabilities range. The range will 0 to 1, and the sum of all the probabilities will be equal to `1`.

Comment: Can't we do that without GPU setting enable ?